# apexcharts - Area chart not filling area

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, apexcharts

I'm trying to make an area chart using apexcharts with nuxt (vue2), but the area is not getting filled, and the options i set in chartOptions for fill are getting used by the line itself instead of the area, as below:

[image: area graph, but the area is not filled]

this is my apexchart component:

```html
<client-only>
  <apexcharts
    type="area"
    width="70%"
    ref="realtimeChart"
    :options="chartOptions"
    :series="series"> 
  </apexcharts>
</client-only>
```

this is my chartOptions:

```json
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          toolbar: {
            show: true,
            tools: {
              download: true,
              selection: false,
              zoom: true,
              zoomin: false,
              zoomout: false,
              pan: false,
              reset: false,
            },
          },
        id: "basic-bar",
        colors: ["#FFA07A"],
        fill: {
          type: "gradient",
          gradient: {
            shadeIntensity: 1,
            opacityFrom: 0.7,
            opacityTo: 0.9,
            stops: [0, 100],
          },
        },
        forecastDataPoints: {
          count: 28,
          strokeWidth: 4,
          dashArray: 5,
        },
        title: {
          text: "doesnt matter",
          align: "center",
        },
        grid: {
          borderColor: "#e7e7e7",
          row: {
            colors: ["#f3f3f3", "transparent"], 
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: "date",
          tickAmount: 40,
        },
        yaxis: [
          {
            title: {
              text: "Mt CO2eq/we",
            },
            forceNiceScale: true,
          },
        ]
      },
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I was declaring **type: "line"** in my series. thats all.